# How to make form entry HttpRequestValidationException friendly in html5

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, html, forms

ASP.NET 4.6 MVC4 application controller processes form POST requests.

If user enters < character to form exception

A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client (... )
occurs.

How to make form entry more user friendly in this case:

1. Allow to show localized error message
2. Do not submit form and show more friendly error in javascript
3. Add some validation patterns to html5 input and textarea elements 
   which show htlm5 validation message in browser for this field.

How to implement this ?

html5, Bootstrap 3, jquery, jquery-ui are used.

Comment: AFAIK, the < character by default associated with HTML tags, which considered dangerous if a user inserts script tag with malicious JS inside it (preventing XSS by design). Friendly localized messages can be set by either resx file or special localized page(s), and combine them with `ValidationMessageFor` set to each user input field bound for your model.

Comment: Custom validation is used. Form is generated dynamically. resx files are not used. How to change error message text to another or add html5 regular expression validation in client side ?